# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array

Tags: laravel

I try to send attachement files but i get

> Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array

I use laravel 5.4

Someone know why i'm getting this error ?

( I don't upload the file into a directory, i just want to send the file who was requested on my controller )

Hope someone could help , best regards :)

Here my controller :

```
public function postSendMassive(Request $request){

        $files = $request->file('uploads');

        $emails = Structure::where('type_structure_id', 4)->pluck('adresse_email_structure');

        $subject = $request->subject;
        $bodyMessage = $request->texte;

        foreach($files as $file) {
            $files[] = [
                'file' => $file->getRealPath(),
                'options' => [
                    'mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
                    'as'    => $file->getClientOriginalName()
                ],
            ];
        }

        Mail::to('test@gmaIL.com')->send(new MassiveEmail($subject , $bodyMessage , $files));

        return back()->with('status', "Email envoyé");

    }
```

here my build mail  :

```
public function build()
    {

        $subject = $this->subject;
        $bodyMessage = $this->bodyMessage;
        $files = $this->files;

        $email =  $this->markdown('email.MassiveMail',compact('bodyMessage'))
            ->subject($subject.'-'.'FFRXIII Licences & Compétitions');


        foreach($this->files as $file) {
            $email->attach($file['file'],$file['options']);
        }

        return $email;
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `$request->file('uploads')` returns an object and you're trying iterate over it with `foreach`

If you want to upload multiple files, make sure you're doing something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple />
```

And iterate over uploaded files:

```
foreach ($request->uploads as $file)
```

Comment: You saved my day ! it works !!!!! the problem was on my foreach !!!! many many thanks !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

This works!

```
    if($request->hasFile('files')){
        
        foreach ($request->files as $file) {
            
            //get file name with extenstion
            $fileNameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            //get just filename
            $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            //get extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //file to store
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

            //upload to store
            $path = $file->storeAs('${your_storage_path}', $fileNameToStore);

            
        }    
        
    }
```

Comment: Why are you returning at the beginning of your foreach loop? If that's intentional you can get rid of any code after it.

Comment: @KarlHill Thanks for pointing that out, it wasn't intentional

Comment: what about size? how can i get size

Comment: get size getSize() worked!!!!