# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array using laravel

Tags: laravel

I tried it but it was an error

```
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array
```

Does anyone have a solution for this ???

Hope someone could help, best regards :)

**controller**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        foreach ($request->file_name as $key => $value) {

            $freedownloadfiles = new FreeDownloadFiles();
            $extension = $request->file('file_upload')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
            $freedownloadfiles->files = Storage::disk('yourstitchart')->putFileAs('', 
            $request->file_upload[$key], $extension);
            $freedownloadfiles->file_name = $value;
            $freedownloadfiles->free_download_id = $freedownload->id;
            $freedownloadfiles->save();
        }

        return redirect()->route('freedownload');
    }
```

Comment: I think you want to support multiple files in your php code, but are only sending 1 via your request. So do you want to process multiple files or just 1?

Comment: I have  removed the loop and then trying to upload multiple files but i am getting error Array to string conversion

Comment: Can you point out in your code which line fails please?

Comment: https://flareapp.io/share/x5Me4Op5#F58  please check it

Comment: Are you certain `$value` is the file name and not the complete file?

Comment: I mean: based on the error you send via the link, I see the error occurs when saving the `$freedownloadfiles` so most likely you entered data into it which does not compute. Maybe try doing this `dd($freedownloadfiles->toArray())` to see the contents?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you get you'r data from ($key => $value) ? i see you get extension from request and you didn't convert it to the parsed data.
When you foreach on array you access to any element it contain . You must access that element with $value !

Send files with html code like :

```
 <input type="file" name="filenames[]" >
```

Get as following :

```
        if($request->hasfile('filenames'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().'.'.$file->extension();
                //write here what do you want 
            }
         }
```

And you can see this answer:
[Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609960/cannot-use-object-of-type-illuminate-http-uploadedfile-as-array?rq=1)